# How can I set the value for an HTML <select>?

Tags: html, select, laravel-8

I needed to set a value for <  select>
so I added a "value=.." to the  element thinking that it will give it a default value.
Is there any way other than `selected` to use, because in my case the value changes from a `candidate` to an other.

*I did this so the user can see first the candidate's service then change it in case of an error..*

```
   <span >Service</span>
      <select  class="form-control item pb-2"  name="service" value={{ $candidate->service->service_name }}>
            <option value="Outsourcing"> <span class="font-weight-bold">Outsourcing</span></option>
            <option value="Developpement"> <span class="font-weight-bold">Developpement</span></option>
            <option value="Call center"> <span class="font-weight-bold">Call center</span></option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a default value for select. Instead, you can do something like this:

```
<select  class="form-control item pb-2"  name="service" >
        <option value={{ $candidate->service->service_name }}>{{ $candidate->service->service_name }}</option>
        <option value="Outsourcing"> <span class="font-weight-bold">Outsourcing</span></option>
        <option value="Developpement"> <span class="font-weight-bold">Developpement</span></option>
        <option value="Call center"> <span class="font-weight-bold">Call center</span></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've already tried this, but I got the same option twice that's why I was looking for an other solution, if there is no other way then I will just use this

Comment: You have to simply use if-else condition

Answer (score 0):

Any option can be set to selected and that will be the default value for the select. That is the standard way of setting the value. Why not use it?

Also options do not have tags inside

```
<select  class="form-control item pb-2"  name="service" >
  <option selected value="{{ $candidate->service->service_name }}">{{ $candidate->service->service_name }}</option>
  <option value="Outsourcing">Outsourcing</option>
  <option value="Development">Development</option>
  <option value="Call center">Call center</option>
</select>
```

If you must insert a new option and select it then you can use JavaScript

```js
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  const sel = document.querySelector("[name=service]");
  const val = "{{ $candidate->service->service_name }}";
  const opts = [new Option(val,val),...sel.options]
  sel.length = 0;
  opts.forEach(opt => sel.appendChild(opt));
  sel.value = val;
})
```

```html
<span>Service</span>
<select class="form-control item pb-2" name="service">
  <option value="Outsourcing">Outsourcing</span></option>
  <option value="Development">Development</option>
  <option value="Call center">Call center</option>
</select>
```